# Workbox precaching does not work with cross origin requests

Tags: workbox, sw-precache, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm using the `precacheAndRoute()` function to precache a bunch of assets passed to a service worker by the `InjectManifest()` function of the `workbox-webpack-plugin` plugin.

This works great, but all of these assets are hosted on a CDN, which means that the requests are cross origin. The problem is that for some reason, Workbox doesn't seem to recognize this, and sends the requests without the `Origin` header, which means that CORS fails.

I tried overriding the default behavior by initializing the `PrecacheController` myself, using a plugin to force the request to operate in `cors` mode:

```js
const precacheController = new PrecacheController({
    cacheName: precacheName,
    plugins: [{
        requestWillFetch: async ({request}) => new Request(request.url, {
            mode: 'cors',
        }),
    }],
});

precacheController.precache(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
registerRoute(new PrecacheRoute(precacheController));
```

Unfortunately, this still doesn't seem to add the `Origin` header. Any ideas what might be causing this and how to work around it?